# Why can't objects be used directly between processes

Tags: serialization, process, multiprocessing

I know that the memory between processes is independent, and messages can be passed through shared memory.

But objects in shared memory cannot be used directly, but need to be serialized and deserialized then used by processes?

Comment: *"But objects in shared memory cannot be used directly,"* What makes you think that? Is there some specific environment where you're hitting that limitation? Please add more detail to the question.

Comment: Of course they can access memory. My question is why serialization is needed

Answer (score -1):

I thought about it carefully, I think it is necessary to distinguish between two situations to treat.

### Simple type

The reason why I think serialization is not necessary is simple type. Suppose we have a structure

```
struct A {
  int a;
  string b;
  double c;
}
```

If this object is copied to memory and then shared with another process, this seems feasible. Other processes only need to read it from memory and parse it.

### User type

But then we consider the following scenario, We have a new structure

```
struct A {
  int a;
  B b;
  double c;
}
```

We know that custom type `b` is a pointer in struct `A`.The memory between 2 processes is not shared, so it’s not enough to pass pointers, we need to copy object b from memory. And this process is serialization!

In fact, whether it is to save objects from memory to files or copy objects to other processes, **serialization is required**.